Discrepancy of general element of linear system
Let $X$ be a normal scheme and $|D|$ a linear system on $X$.
In "Singularity of Minimal Model Program" by Janos kollar p249, it says,
If $X$ is a variety over $\mathbb{C}$, and $E_j$ countably many divisors over $X$,
Then for very general element $D_1,D_2\in |D|$, an equality holds about there discrepancy
as
$a(E_j,X,D_1)=a(E_j,X,D_2)$
How can we show this equality?
